# Ajax: Why is the post request fired twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have noticed my request is fired twice, but I dont understand why.

I have a simple form:

```
<form method="POST" class="mb-4" autocomplete="off" action="/recipe/add" novalidate id="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Rezeptname</label>
        <input required type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control form-control-sm needs-validation" value="">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Ein Name wird für das Rezept benötigt!</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cookingTime">Zubereitungsdauer in Minuten</label>
        <input type="number" name="cookingTime" id="cookingTime" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="servings">Portionen</label>
        <input type="number" name="servings" id="servings" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="">
    </div>

    <label for="ingredients">Zutaten</label>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm ml-2" onclick="createInputRow()"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>

    <div class="mb-4" name="ingredients">
        <table class="table">
            <tbody id="tbody">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="submit">Speichern</button>
    <a href="javascript:history.back()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Zurück</a>
</form>
```

on document load, I add the event listener for the button

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $("#submit").unbind("click").bind("click", event => {
        onSubmit(event)
    })
})
```

in the onSubmit method, the request is sent out:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/recipe/add",
        data: {recipe: recipeData},
        success: (res) => {
            console.log(JSON.parse(res))
        }
    });
```

In the network scan I could see that the request is fired twice.
[image: Network scan]

This leads to getting an error on my server.
When setting a breakpoint in the front end, it is only triggered once, though. The backend recieves two requests like in the network scan.

I already tried the $("#submit").unbind().bind() as mentioned in other sources but that doesnt fix the problem.

Comment: You need to take the "type" of submit off -- `type="submit"`  -- OR use `preventDefault()` inside your action.  --  It's trying to fire the form natively AND use your custom jQuery.

Comment: Really to be honest .. You don't need the `<form>` tags at all since you are handling the form inputs with your own `AJAX` call ..

Comment: @Zak Thank you! I have overseen that totally.

Comment: I wanted to keep it as a form so that it will do the redirection on its own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case that you want to use your `<form>` tag for other purposes (including redirect) --  You should remove the `type=submit` off the submit button, OR use `preventDefault()` to prevent the default form action.   Also note that hitting the "Enter" key *may also submit the form* if in an text field.  You can also use `preventDefault()` to prevent the form from being submitted during this action as well.